# Series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does this serie converges or not?

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}  {\arctan(n)}.
$$
I was thinking about the root test:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}  {\arctan(n)^\frac{1}{n}}.
$$
The n-squareroot will scale the $\arctan(n)$ too almost $0$, which means that the n-term will go to infinity....not converges.

If I am wrong please give me a hint and not the answer.

Comment: $\sqrt[n]n \to 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Do the individual terms approach $0$?

Comment: no they do not, but it is an alternating serie. According to my prof. that is not a " good enough" answer.

Comment: Any series, alternating or not, must diverge if the individual terms don't approach $0$ as a limit.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\text{Is}\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\arctan n}=0\;\;?$$

Comment: Or: does it even exist?

Comment: @AlexR Indeed, yet for the question's purpose it is enough to answer the above question.

Comment: the limit does not exist due to alternating serie. But that was not "good enough" as answer, according to the prof.

Comment: @Oskar I think that's the prof's problem...and probably his students' as well: **any** converging series' general term's sequence **must** converge to zero, either alternating or not. Anyway, who cares about the alternating stuff: in fact, $\;\arctan n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac\pi2\;$ , so **also** without the alternating signs that thing doesn't converge to zero.

Comment: @Timbuc Well thats a grey area. $\frac{1}{k}$ diverge while $\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$ converge. a.k.a alternating harmonic serie.

Comment: @oskar "grey area"...for whom? In the case you mention we have that $\;\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}0\;$, in your question' case you do NOT have. The condition is necessary (not sufficient!) and thus your series diverges, and the series $\;\sum\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k\;$ converges by Leibniz Text, which isn't appliable in your case.